# How to include javascript file in a specific tag?

Tags: javascript

Ok, I've got this function:

```
/* jsHandler.js */
function inc(filename)
{
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0);
script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = filename;
script.type = 'text/javascript';
body.appendChild(script)
}
```

What i would like is extending the script to tell js where to insert the js.file, like, say i have this in html:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<iframe id="myiframe"></iframe>
```

i call

```
inc(this.js, mydiv)
```

to include the js.file in the div "mydiv",

resulting in:

```
<div id="mydiv"><script src="this.js" type="text/javascript"></script></div>
```

How do i do that?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @DarkFalcon made a a valid point. There is no reason to include script files within nodes, it just makes no difference. The script gets evaluated and executed by your browser anyway.

Comment: Anticipating a future question "how to tell what tag script is executing in"

Comment: What was it called? An XY question?

Comment: @DarkFalcon Because it doesn't work in all browsers if i don't include the scripts in a certain order (i have js code in head and body).

Comment: Scripts added after the fact like you are doing load asychronously.  There is no defined load order.  If you need a defined load order, then you are going to have to manually wait for one script to finish loading before inserting the next one.  Inserting them into a different place in your document will not make a difference in their load order - only the time that you insert them will control that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
/* jsHandler.js */
function inc(filename,target)
{
var targetelement= document.getElementById(target); // get the target element
script = document.createElement('script'); 
script.src = filename;
script.type = 'text/javascript';
targetelement.appendChild(script); // add the script to the target
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what i was looking for! Great! And thank you for your quick response - and sorry for my late one!!!

Answer (score 1):

You always pick your `body` element

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0);
```

and simply append the `script` tag to it:

```
body.appendChild(script)
```

**What you want to do**
Pick your target element and append it there.

```
var target = document.getElementsById(mydiv);
// ... other code lines
target.appendChild(script)
```

Comment: Yeah, i knew that, but although I`m able to tell what needs to be changed, I'm not there yet in js, to do it myself... :-(Thank you very much!